# How to tell angular (2) currency pipe to display as it is if value is a string not int or float

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

The currency pipe should be smart enough to handle `string`, `float`, `int`, etc automatically.

if passed value is `string` or not `int` or `float`, it should do nothing and display the passed value as it is. And only display formatted value if it is `int` or `float`.

It was happening in angularJs but not happening in angular (2)

How to tell currency pipe to escape in case its `string` and do currency formatting if its a `decimal` value. I am expecting something like below.

#### Example

`<div>Money:{{'xxx/vv/cc' | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</div>` should display
`xxx/vv/cc`

`<div>Money: {{''11.99'' | currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2'}}</div>`
should display `$11.99` --$ symbol included.

But its not happening. Error I am getting is `caused by: Invalid argument 'Included' for pipe 'CurrencyPipe'`

I think it was happening by default in angularjs but in angular2 its not happening by defalut.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/CurrencyPipe-pipe.html) explicitly states that it accepts a numeric expression and nothing else:

> number_expression | currency[:currencyCode[:symbolDisplay[:digitInfo]]]

The pipe is [really simple](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L127-L164) and can be extended and used instead of `CurrencyPipe` to conform to the expected behaviour:

```
const _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP = /^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/;

@Pipe({name: 'currency'})
export class LooseCurrencyPipe extends CurrencyPipe {
  transform(value: any, currencyCode: string, symbolDisplay: boolean, digits: string): string {
    if (typeof value === 'number' || _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP.test(value)) {
      return super.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

To create a new pipe with different name, `CurrencyPipe` may be injected into custom pipe:

```
@Pipe({name: 'looseCurrency'})
export class LooseCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

  transform(value: any, currencyCode: string, symbolDisplay: boolean, digits: string): string {
    if (typeof value === 'number' || _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP.test(value)) {
      return this._currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

In order for `CurrencyPipe` to be injected through DI, it should be additionally added to module providers:

```
declarations: [LooseCurrencyPipe, ...],
providers: [CurrencyPipe, ...],
```

Comment: I tried the same way you shown here but it did not work for me. plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/cxRU2NB7S0AQKSevmNQT?p=info

Comment: This works when being used like the answer states, i.e. [overriding `currency` pipe with new implementation](http://plnkr.co/edit/pYW5Jiqvt4entqBmbdTQ). The framework isn't happy when extended pipe is renamed. To do a thing like you're trying to do, [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) approach will [work fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/zeEmnGGkGrcHn5TpmZcw).

Answer (score 11):

You can use the ternary operator `a ? b : c` to show `b` when `a` is truthy, but show `c` otherwise.

First have a function in your component that returns `true` when the value is a number.

**component**

```
isNumber(e) {return typeof e === 'number'}
```

Then use that to determine whether to send the value to the currency pipe or print it directly

**template**

```
<div>
    {{ isNumber(money) ? (money|currency:'USD':true:'1.2-2') : money }}  
</div>
```

[**live demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/V1swVmINzxS3AxDKjaWX?p=preview)

Comment: you should not use a function inside a template.