# angular extended currency pipe in is not formatting string/int if there is no decimal point in input

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

Angular currency pipe is not converting string/int to currency format if the number is in string format and there is no decimal points in the string.

suppose the amount is 12 and I want to show $12.00, if "12" is passed, its not showing but if 12.00 is passed its working properly.

```
//Code

import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";
import {CurrencyPipe} from "@angular/common";
const _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP = /^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/;

@Pipe({name: 'myCurrency'})
export class MyCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform  {
  constructor (private _currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

  transform(value: any, currencyCode: string, symbolDisplay: boolean, digits: string): string {
    if (typeof value === 'number' || _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP.test(value)) {
      return this._currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <div>{{priceNoDecimal}}</div> {{priceNoDecimal | myCurrency}}
      <div>{{priceWithDecimal}}</div> {{priceWithDecimal | myCurrency}}      
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  priceWithDecimal: string;
  priceNoDecimal: string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2',
    this.priceNoDecimal = "12"
    this.priceWithDecimal = "12.00"
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App , MyCurrencyPipe],
  providers: [CurrencyPipe],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}


//output

Hello Angular2

12
12
12.00
USD12.00
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UONxA2?p=preview)

Comment: What do you mean? Both `"12"` and `"12.00"` are transformed to `USD12.00`.

Comment: The example plunker you linked to works perfectly well, in the first line you aren't applying the pipe transform inside the div.

Comment: @StefanSvrkota yes. that is what I want  but its not happening

Comment: @silentsod, I edited the plunker now. please check https://plnkr.co/edit/UONxA2?p=preview

Comment: ...and that *still* demonstrates that it's working correctly. Are you using a browser that needs the `Intl` polyfill?

Comment: @silentsod. wow, I see it now. In the pllunker its working but not in my code. I already spent 4-5 hours on this. moght be some issue in my code.

Comment: @silentsod, actually its happening when i extend currency pipe out of that. look into the code I modified

Comment: This is nothing to do with Angular 2 or its pipes; `/^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/` [doesn't match `"12"`](https://regex101.com/r/7K3zGR/1). Try some basic debugging next time, you could have isolated this from the Angular framework entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the regexp that you have applied: `/^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/` it requires a decimal point.

The following regex makes the decimal point optional `/^(\d+)?\.?((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/`

Comment: Why would you mix `?` and `{0,1}`?

Comment: I am incredibly lazy. Only take 0 or 1.

Comment: That doesn't make sense, it would have been lazier to use the single character.

Comment: Honestly, regex is not my strong suit. I had to go look up ? to determine what it does. Thanks, though @jonrsharpe because you did get me to learn something new about regex today. I have altered my initial answer to use the shorter form.

Answer (score 1):

The question may be unclear without the context. The pipe from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40166034/3731501) is the regex [that is used in original number pipes](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L16) to detect numbers in strings:

```
const _NUMBER_FORMAT_REGEXP = /^(\d+)?\.((\d+)(-(\d+))?)?$/;
```

In order for it to to closely mimic [input conditioning of original currency pipe](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0/modules/%40angular/common/src/pipes/number_pipe.ts#L23-L27), the pipe may be changed to:

```
function isNumeric(value: any): boolean {
  return !isNaN(value - parseFloat(value));
}

@Pipe({name: 'looseCurrency'})
export class LooseCurrencyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

  transform(value: any, currencyCode: string, symbolDisplay: boolean, digits: string): string {
    value = typeof value === 'string' && isNumeric(value) ? +value : value;

    if (typeof value === 'number') {
      return this._currencyPipe.transform(value, currencyCode, symbolDisplay, digits);
    } else {
      return value;
    }
  }
}
```

Where `isNumeric` is a helper function that was extracted from [framework internals](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.1.0/modules/%40angular/facade/src/lang.ts#L182). It should [work fine](http://plnkr.co/edit/MhIiQrowa4fyVXKT2SIW) with this approach.

Comment: You got me ;). Now I think I am laziest to person in the earth. I would have solved it myself